# It is possible to implement a regression algorithm using Random Forests?

Tags: regression, random-forest, weka

I have to write code to implement regression using random forests (by default Weka provides random forests for classification). Is this possible to do?

Comment: It is certainly in the realm of possibility. But what is your question? If this is purely about Weka programming, it is off-topic. If you are interested in a particular statistical aspect of RF regression, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: This is what random forests are for, no? For regression! So random forests already are a regression algorithm. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that WEKA 3.7's RandomForest implementation supports a numeric class attribute, whereas 3.6 did not.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible. Both [python](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) and [R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) have implementations of random forests for regression.  Perhaps your should change tools?

Or you can use [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) to run R from within Java.